# Data collection frequency strategy

Tags: web-scraping, google-bigquery, data-science, bigdata

I have a question and I am wondering if anyone has solved this problem effectively. I am developing a collector(let's call it A) to collect data from a source(let's call it B) which in turn collects data from somewhere else. B collects every 5 minutes, what frequency or strategy should A use ? If A's frequency is double of B then it will end up with duplicate data for an interval. If it's the same as B then there's a chance that it may get stale data if the collection times are exactly the same. Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If there is some sort of time data associated with the data you are collecting from source B, then you could use that to exclude duplicate results; you could set it to only include new data with a more recent timestamp.

I have done this before by converting date/time to a Unix Epoch Timestamp and then checking that the latest data has a larger value, or else ignoring it. This would allow you to run your data collection at twice the rate of B's, if you desired to.

Comment: That's a good idea but when I am dealing with massive data, I do not want to risk storing that data in memory while I wait for the second poll data to turn up. I would want to have it pushed to the destination asap.